# MySQL Slow SELECT Query

Tags: mysql, performance, select, indexing

I have a query, which is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE confirmed = 0
AND resource = 123
AND id IN (
  SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE resource = 123
  AND added > 1440000000
)
```

It takes nearly 3 minutes to run, but I have no idea why. Here's why I'm confused...

```
SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE resource = 123
AND added > 1440000000
```

There are no results for this sub-query. Not a single one. So, I thought if I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE confirmed = 0
AND resource = 123
AND id IN (
 0
)
```

It should take about the same time to run. Except it doesn't - it instantly returns 0 results as expected. What's going on? What's the different to comparing an empty query result to 0?

The row numbers are pretty low too. I've run an explain and it's using the confirmed key for table 1 and the primary key from table 2. The row count is 5500 / 20000 respectively.

Any ideas would be very gratefully received! Thank you!

Comment: Because for each row `SELECT` executed in your statement. Isn't more suitable to use `JOIN` here? Correct me if I missed smth.

Comment: If you've run the explain it might be a good idea to include it.

Comment: Are you sure that the resource and the added fields are indexed in your database?

Comment: Paul, I think you're right - although it's 0 results, it's probably taking some time to run each subquery for every row. I thought the optimiser would do the sub query once, hold it in memory, and then compare the results each time but it doesn't appear so. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Thanks Jacub and ITOctopus too for your suggestions. I've changed the field names etc. for the question, so I thought it would be easier to just explain the 'explain' rather than change it all. There are indexes on the resource and added fields as suggested. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would run faster using an explicit `join`.  If the subquery doesn't return duplicate values:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE resource = 123 AND added > 1440000000
     ) t2
     ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE confirmed = 0 AND resource = 123;
```

Also, MySQL is often better optimizing `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE confirmed = 0 AND resource = 123 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table2 t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t1.id AND t2.resource = 123 AND t2.added > 1440000000
                 );
```

This query will run faster with an index on `table2(id, resource, added)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, that's very useful. I'm guessing that although the sub query returns no results, it still takes a significant enough amount of time to run. I'll change my query and hopefully that will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

`IN ( SELECT ... )` Optimizes very poorly before 5.6.  5.6 is better, but still not great.

`JOIN ( SELECT ... )` must be computed first, and requires a temp table.  So it is not as good as a plain JOIN as below.

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  table1 AS t1
    JOIN  table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
    WHERE  t1.confirmed = 0
      AND  t1.resource = 123
      AND  t2.resource = 123
      AND  t2.added > 1440000000
```

And have

```
table2:  INDEX(resource, added)
table1:  INDEX(resource, confirmed)
```

Comment: More discussion:  [Index Cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).